# Permamently get "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR" When calling "/v1/payments/payment"

Tags: php, api, paypal, payment

Currently I'm trying to implement PayPal via Rest API. I've read the documentation and I wrote a script which executes all calls to the Rest API with the givin example JSJON Objects (from the documentation).

Unfortunately I get following answer object (since several days) when calling https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

```
object(stdClass)[1181]
      public 'name' => string 'INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR' (length=22)
      public 'message' => string 'An internal service error has occurred' (length=38)
      public 'information_link' => string 'https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR' (length=79)
      public 'debug_id' => string 'c23de45eb8631' (length=13)
```

The data I sent

```
{"intent":"sale","payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"amount":{"currency":"EUR","total":"74.90"},"description":"This is the payment transaction description.","invoice_number":null,"item_list":{"items":[{"quantity":1,"name":"Hammerfall-DE","description":"Heavy Metal Klassiker der schwedischen Band Hammerfall mit sehr eing\u00e4ngigem, hymnischem Chorus, hohem M\u00e4nnergesang, melodischen Gitarren sowie nach vorne gehenden Double-Bass-Drums. Klingt sehr positiv. (Artist: Hammerfall) DE","pr'... (length=729)
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: INternal service error means PayPal's code crashed/broke trying to answer your request. There is probably some aspect of your request that triggered PayPal's error, but it's still a failure on their side. Ping PayPal QA with the correlation ID and they should look into what happened, tell you how to avoid the error, and then they can also fix their code so that the next developer who submits a similar transaction can get a meaningful response code.

Comment: Eshan is right. Can you please reduce the description to less than 127, and try again. However, I agree with geewiz, we should be throwing a bit better response than this. I have sent an email asking to create a bug for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be it is because of the description that you have given for item_list object `description` .The maximum length mentioned according to the docs should be 127 characters . Can you try to reduce it to 127 chars and try once again :

You can refer the docs here :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#item-object